# How to attain this logic

Tags: php, symfony, if-statement

I'm confusing myself and I cannot figure out how to write this logic out in code.

```
if (x == y){
 use x down below
}elseif (d == y){
 use d down below
}else{
 do z
}

do some stuff here using x or d or z
```

Does that make sense? I thought a simple `return d, x, or z` would do the trick but it does not. I'm trying to do it this way in order to not duplicate code because the same thing (more or less) would be done in each of those cases.

I'm using symfony2 and am new to it.

Comment: Have you tried using `switch()` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if ($x == $y) {
  $value = $x;
} else if ($d == $y) {
  $value = $d;
} else {
  $value = $z;
}

doSomething($value);
```

Comment: I think the else if() is supposed to be `$value = $d;` ?

Comment: @Andreas: you are correct, my mistake. But since `$d == $y`, the result is the same (well as far as == comparison goes).

Comment: I think that makes sense. Yes thank you for clearing that up in my head

Comment: Yes. But just thought you should know before the "downvote squad" enters the thread